# 5º step usando jquery.smartWizard.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Tenho o seguinte menu de formulário usando jquery.smartWizard.js

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso inserir o 5º passo e não estou conseguindo. Como faço para inserir?

Segue abaixo o código da minha tela.

```
<!-- Tabs -->
<div id="wizard_verticle" class="form_wizard wizard_verticle">
    <ul class="list-unstyled wizard_steps">
        <li>
            <a href="#step-1">
                <span class="step_no">1</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#step-2">
                <span class="step_no">2</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#step-3">
                <span class="step_no">3</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#step-4">
                <span class="step_no">4</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#step-5">
                <span class="step_no">5</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="step-1" class="show-tab">
        <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" name="tagForm">
            <span class="section">Dados Basicos</span>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="last-name">
                    Nome <span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tag.Nome" ng-required="true" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                    Descrição <span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tag.Descricao" ng-required="true" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                    Status <span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                    <select class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ng-model="tag.Ativo" ng-options="Ativo.value as Ativo.status for Ativo in Status" ng-required="true">
                        <option value="">Selecione opção</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                    Dispositivos<span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                    <select class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ng-model="tag.dispositivoId" ng-options="Dispositivo.Id as Dispositivo.Nome for Dispositivo in Dispositivos" ng-required="true">
                        <option value="">Selecione opção</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="step-2" class="show-tab">
        <span class="section">Configuração</span>
        <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" name="tagForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                    Endereço <span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tag.Endereco" ng-required="true" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                    Envios<span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                    <select class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ng-model="tag.ClasseDeEnvio" ng-options="EClasseDeEnvio.Value as EClasseDeEnvio.Nome for EClasseDeEnvio in EClassesDeEnvios" ng-required="true">
                        <option value="">Selecione opção</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                    Varredura<span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                    <select class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ng-model="tag.ClasseDeVarredura" ng-options="EClasseDeVarredura.Value as EClasseDeVarredura.Nome for EClasseDeVarredura in EClassesDeVarreduras" ng-required="true">
                        <option value="">Selecione opção</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                    Tipo de dados<span class="required">*</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                    <select class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ng-model="tag.TipoDeDado"  ng-options="ETipoDeDado.Value as ETipoDeDado.Nome for ETipoDeDado in ETipoDeDados" ng-required="true">
                        <option value="">Selecione opção</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="step-3" class="show-tab">
        <span class="section">Parametros</span>
        <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" name="tagForm">
            <span class="section" ng-if="tag.TipoDeDado === undefined">Selecione um Tipo de dado para essa Tag.</span>
            <div class="tagDigitalForm" ng-if="tag.TipoDeDado === 0 && tag.TipoDeDado !== undefined">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                        Mensagem para valor verdadeiro
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                        <textarea rows="4" placeholder="" ng-model="tag.MensagemValorTrue"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                        Mensagem para valor falso
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                        <textarea rows="4" placeholder="" ng-model="tag.MensagemValorFalse" name="tag.MensagemValorFalse"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="tagAnalogicaForm" ng-if="tag.TipoDeDado !== 0 && tag.TipoDeDado !== undefined">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                        Banda Morta
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="tag.BandaMorta" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                        Exibição
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tag.FormatoExibicao" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                        Menor Valor
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tag.MenorValor" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                        Maior Valor
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tag.MaiorValor" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                        Un. de Eng.°
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tag.UnidadeDeEngenharia" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


    <div id="step-4" class="show-tab">
        <span class="section">Alarmes</span>
        <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" name="tagForm">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                    Criar Alarme
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="tag.hasAlarme">
                        <option value="0" selected>Não</option>
                        <option value="1">Sim</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div ng-show="tag.hasAlarme == 1 && tag.TipoDeDado !== 0 && tag.TipoDeDado !== undefined">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                            Valor
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Alarme Alto" ng-model="tag.ValorAlarmeAlto" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                            Mensagem
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Alarme Alto" ng-model="tag.MensagemAlarmeAlto" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!---------------->

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                            Valor
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Alarme Muito Alto" ng-model="tag.ValorAlarmeMuitoAlto" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                            Mensagem
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Alarme Muito Alto" ng-model="tag.MensagemAlarmeMuitoAlto" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!---------------->

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                            Valor
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Alarme Baixo" ng-model="tag.ValorAlarmeBaixo" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                            Mensagem
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Alarme Baixo" ng-model="tag.MensagemAlarmeBaixo" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!---------------->

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                            Valor
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tag.ValorAlarmeMuitoBaixo" placeholder="Alarme Muito Baixo" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                            Mensagem
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tag.MensagemAlarmeMuitoBaixo" placeholder="Alarme Muito Baixo" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div ng-show="tag.hasAlarme == 1 && tag.TipoDeDado === 0 && tag.TipoDeDado !== undefined">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                        Mensagem em Alarme
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tag.MensagemAlarme" placeholder="Alarme Muito Baixo" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3" for="first-name">
                        Valor em Alarme
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                        <select class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" ng-model="tag.ValorAlarme" ng-options="obj.value as obj.status for obj in ValorAlarme" ng-required="true">
                            <option value="">Selecione opção</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                <!---------------->

    </form>
    </div>

    <div id="step-5" class="show-tab">
        <span class="section">Tendencia</span>
        <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" name="tagForm">
        </form>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- End SmartWizard Content -->





<style>
    #wizard_verticle .show-tab {
        height: 370px;
    }
</style>


<!-- jQuery Smart Wizard -->
<script src="/vendors/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/js/jquery.smartWizard.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Smart Wizard -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#wizard').smartWizard();

        $('#wizard_verticle').smartWizard({
            transitionEffect: 'slide'
        });


        $('.buttonFinish').addClass('btn btn-default');
        $('.buttonNext').addClass('btn btn-success');
        $('.buttonPrevious').addClass('btn btn-primary');

        $('.buttonFinish').attr('ng-click', 'adicionar(tag)');


    });
</script>
<!-- /jQuery Smart Wizard -->
```

Fiz uma tentativa para inserir o step-5 só que não deu certo, não apareceu na tela e nem me retornou um erro.

Comment: Jovem, ninguém vai ler 365 linhas de códigos pra tentar te ajudar. Por favor, tente ser mais sucinto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limpa o cache do navegador que vai funcionar